# Do the Vulnerable and Defenseless conditions affect the Deflect effect?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

So I was looking at the Deflect effect, in M&M 3E.

Normally, the Vulnerable condition causes someone to half their Active Defenses. The Defenseless condition puts them at zero.

The Deflect effect seems like it *replaces* an active defenses; which makes it seem like it would be unaffected. However, it also requires a Defend action, which makes it seem like it *is* an active defense.

So my question is this. Do Vulnerable and Defenseless affect the Deflect effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of Deflect indicates that the power is used in place of an Active Defense, but does not state that Deflect itself is an Active Defense, so I believe it is not affected by Vulnerable or Defenseless, although circumstances and descriptors might work otherwise (if your Deflect power is stated to be a function of your swordwork, and you're currently paralyzed, you're not going to be able to swing your sword into place).